# /usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libavformat.a(http.o): undefined reference to symbol 'inflateInit2_' in C/C++ Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse-cdt

i've got this error when building my project
`/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libavformat.a(http.o): undefined reference to symbol 'inflateInit2_'`

i've search for the solution, there's a reference that i have to install zlib. i've installed it,but the error still showing.

Comment: Have you linked the new library? Also, on Stack Overflow, you will generally get berated if you don't post the code that causes this error. Or at least post your dependencies.

Comment: yes, i have.
i don't post the code because i think this isn't a code error.
i've develop it at my PC, and this error is at my other PC. i've already add all lib.